# Getting null on property of 2º level upper related entity( one to many) using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

My context has `Category` entity which houses set of `SubCategories` entities which has a set of `Instruments` entities.

I'm creating a Bootstrap breadcrumb on cshtml view with Razor language.
For a given Instrument(Details method in controller) I need access to my related `Category`.

I can access to my related Subcategory and even `SubCategory.CategoryId` but I don't know why `Category.Name` gives me null.

The code:

```html
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"> <!-- Getting SubCategory.Category=NULL -->
        @Html.ActionLink(Model.SubCategory.Category.Name, "Details", "Categories", new { id = @Model.SubCategory.CategoryId }, null)
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
        @Html.ActionLink(Model.SubCategory.Name, "Details", "SubCategories", new { id = @Model.SubCategoryId }, null)
    </li> 
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">@Model.Name</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by passing the category name in a ViewBag:

```cs
   var CatName = from c in _context.Category
   where c.Id == instrument.SubCategory.CategoryId
   select c.Name;
   ViewBag.catName = CatName.FirstOrDefault();
```

And setting an `string @categoryName` with the ViewBag passed to the View.